# C#: How do I round a decimal and assign it to an int16?

Tags: c#, decimal, int

I have these variables:

```
Int16 value;
decimal x, y;
```

I tried to do this

```
value = (x * 6) / y;
```

but got a compiler error.
Ideally, I'd like to result of the calculation rounded before assigning it to value.
How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
value = (Int16)Math.Round((x*6)/y);
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
int value = Convert.ToInt16((x * 6) / y)
```

Answer (score 1):

value = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Round((x*6)/y));

Answer (score 1):

int value = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Round((x*6)/y);

Answer (score 1):

I think you must perform a typecast before assigning it to a int16 value.